# How to find the value of outer function from the value of the inner function in composition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Given that $f(x) = \frac{2}{x^3}-\frac{3}{x^2}$ let $x$ be dependent upon $t$, thus $g(t) = f(x(t))$. In case $t=2$, $x = \frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = -8$, what is the value of $g'(t)$ when $t=2$?

This is a multiple choice question in our test on calculus and the answer is $81$. I calculated $\quad f'(x) = \frac{6(x-1)}{x^4}$ first and then calculating $\quad f'(\frac{2}{3})$ which gives $-\frac{81}{8}$. I guess we arrive at the answer by $-\frac{81}{8} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$ but I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain rule for derivatives:

$\dfrac{dg}{dt} = \dfrac{dg}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}$. In this case for $t = 2$, $\dfrac{dg}{dx} = \dfrac{-81}{8}$ and  $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -8$, then $\dfrac{dg}{dt} = 81$